# A square matrix $A$ is such that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{k}) = \mathrm{rank}(A^{k+1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> A square matrix $A$ is such that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{k})=\mathrm{rank}(A^{k+1})$. Then $\mathrm{rank}(A^{k})=\mathrm{rank}(A^{k+i})$ for all $i$.

I think we prove this by induction on $i$.

Let $i = 2$. We show that rank $(A^{k})$ = rank $(A^{k+2})$.

Now, we know that rank $(A^{k+2})$ = rank $(A^{k+1}A)$ $\le$ min (rank$(A^{k+1})$, rank$(A)$) $\le$ rank $(A^{k+1})$ = rank $(A^{k})$.

However, I cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

Think geometrically. We have $A^{k+1}=A^kA$, so the image of $A^{k+1}$ is contained in the image of $A^k$. If the rank of the two are equal, that means the image is the same. Since $A^{k+1}=AA^k$, this means that $A$ is a bijection on said image.

Answer (score 1):

This can be nicely shown by thinking of $A$ as a linear transformation $f \colon K^n \to K^n$ and looking at the decreasing chain $\operatorname{im} f^p \supseteq \operatorname{im} f^{p+1}$ as follows:

If $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(K)$ then let $f \colon K^n \to K^n$ with $f(x) = Ax$ be the associated endomorphism of $K^n$, and let $R_p := \operatorname{im} f^p$ for all $p \geq 0$.
Then
$$
    \operatorname{rank} A^p
  = \dim \operatorname{im} f^p 
  = \dim R_p
  \quad
  \text{for all $p \geq 0$},
$$
as well as
$$
    f(R_p)
  = f(\operatorname{im} f^p)
  = \operatorname{im} f^{p+1}
  = R_{p+1}
  \quad
  \text{for all $p \geq 0$}.
$$

Because we have a decreasing chain
$$
            K^n
  =         R_0
  \supseteq R_1
  \supseteq R_2
  \supseteq R_3
  \supseteq \dotsb
$$
it follows from $\operatorname{rank} A^{k+1} = \operatorname{rank} A^k$ that $\dim R_{k+1} = \dim R_k$ and thus $R_{k+1} = R_k$.

It then further follows that
$$
    R_{k+2}
  = f(R_{k+1})
  = f(R_k)
  = R_{k+1},
$$
and we find inductively that $R_{k+j} = R_{k+j+1}$ for all $j \geq 0$.
So we have
$$
    R_k
  = R_{k+1}
  = R_{k+2}
  = R_{k+3}
  = \dotsb
$$
and thus $R_{k+i} = R_k$ for all $i \geq 0$.

Answer (score -1):

so you know now that $rank (A^k)=rank (A^{k+1})=rank (A^{k+2})$.
you just can take $k'=k+1$  and do the same work for $A^{k'}$. You obtain $$rank (A^k)=rank (A^{k+1})=rank (A^{k'})=rank (A^{k'+1})=rank (A^{k'+2})= rank (A^{(k+1)+2}) = rank (A^{k+3}) $$ and so on