# Matrix power rank problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Prove that for a square matrix $A$ with $\mathrm{rank}(A^2) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$, we also have that $\mathrm{rank}(A^k) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$ for all $k\ge 2$.

I used the inequality of Frobenius to see that
$$\mathrm{rank}(A^2) + \mathrm{rank}(A^2) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) +\mathrm{rank}(A^3).$$

Then utilizing the given equality we see that $\mathrm{rank}(A) \le \mathrm{rank}(A^3)$ which along with the inequality
$$\mathrm{rank}(AB) \le \min(\mathrm{rank}(A),\mathrm{rank}(B))$$
would imply that $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(A^3)$.

Is this proof valid? I understand I need to deal with the rest of the $k$ through the same process.

Comment: I think you can do this one in a more straightforward way. Think about what $A$ does to $\mathop{\rm im} A$.

Comment: Implicit in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949479/a-square-matrix-a-is-such-that-rank-ak-rank-ak1-then-rank (which has answers, but no accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid proof. For another proof using linear transformations and their images see [A square matrix $A$ is such that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{k}) = \mathrm{rank}(A^{k+1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949479).